# One month missing when generating a list of dates using date and mktime()

Tags: php, date, datetime

Im trying to generate a list of months along with the year and 1st date of the month.

I use the below code, but oddly February is missing and March is being repeated 2 times

Code

```
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++):

        $year='2013';

        $month_numb = date($year.'-m-01', mktime(0,0,0,$i));

        echo $month_numb.'<br>';

        endfor;
```

Output

```
2013-01-01
2013-03-01
2013-03-01
2013-04-01
2013-05-01
2013-06-01
2013-07-01
2013-08-01
2013-09-01
2013-10-01
2013-11-01
2013-12-01
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today is the 30th Jan.  Dates in Feburary go up to only 28 this year.  `mktime()` uses today's date for values not supplied.  Since 30th Feburary is invalid, `mktime()` rolls over to the next valid date - `01 March 2013`.

Change your code

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++):
    $month_numb = date('Y-m-01', mktime(0,0,0,$i, 1, 2013));
    echo $month_numb.'<br>';
endfor;
```

The above assigns the day/year to the code and then translates it, rather than taking today's values.

Comment: thanks for the reply and it worked great. It was really odd coz few days before it worked perfect and today it didn't work :D

Answer (score 2):

When calling mktime(), the default day of the month is the current day of the month (in today's case, it's 30.) Since Feb 30 is actually March 2nd (most of the time), that's why mktime(0,0,0,2) will return the month of March.

Give the day of the month to mktime, mktime(0,0,0,$i,1).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to do it without `date` and `mktime` ?

```
$year = 2013;
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ) {
  $month_numb = $year . '-' . $i . '-01';
  echo $month_numb . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to his question though.

Comment: However it is a proposition to not invent a wheel again.

Comment: I agree in a way, but if I'd ask "Why is my chocolate cake always burning?" I'd expect an answer to that and not a "Just buy a pre-made one in the supermarket."

Comment: i tried that before but i cant save it in my mysql database in date format.

Comment: Sure. I let others to answer for this question and I am still proposing other (better?) way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). It's simpler:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++)
{
    echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d') . "<br>\n";
    $datetime->modify('+1 month');
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/t0erHI)

Answer (score 0):

This is because today it's the 30th. And there is no 30th of February. Tomorrow you will have the same issue with all months with 30 days only. And on Feb 1st, your problems will be gone again.

The fix, add the 5th parameter, don't let the day of month default to today's date:

```
$month_numb = date($year.'-m-01', mktime(0,0,0,$i, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The fifth parameter of `mktime` will be set to **today's** day: (from [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php): `... int $day = date("j") ...`), which is 30 (of January). 30th of February doesn't exist, so it goes to March.

You'll see it will work correctly the first of february.